# mysql `having` operation with specific @variable value

Tags: mysql, sql

I give `rank` to each row by its create_time in table instances group by (task_id, task_time) as primary key.I My SQL is as following

```
 SELECT
 task_id,
 task_time,
 create_time,
 @rn := CASE WHEN @prev_task_id <> task_id THEN 1
        WHEN @prev_task_time <> task_time THEN 1
        ELSE @rn + 1 END AS rank,
 @prev_task_id := task_id,
 @prev_task_time := task_time
 FROM instances, (SELECT
                  @rn := 0,
                  @prev_task_id := -1,
                  @prev_task_time := '-1') t
 where task_id in (1209, 1211)
 having rank = 1 
 ORDER BY task_id, task_time DESC, create_time DESC;
```

Question comes After I add `having rank = 1` clause. The returning result is not accurate compared with the result without `having rank = 1` and is missing some records whose rank is also 1, for example, most records with `task_id = 1211` are missing.

As I know , `having` clause is launched after `select` for add filter to the final records. I want to know the mistakes I've made, THX.

Comment: Try to put "groupBy rank" before the having.

Comment: Why are you using `having`? Read about it. It will implictly `group by` all columns and if you `set sql_mode='only_full_group_by'` or use 5.7+ you will be told you are using non-standard behaviour since it doesn't make sense to `select` a column not grouped on. Whatever you want, this query isn't doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34115174/3404097

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. In my opinion, `having` works for the aggregate values. If `set sql_mode='only_full_group_by' is `not set, it doesn't work correctly and becomes undefined behavior.Is it?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.  So, you cannot assign a variable and then use it in another expression -- and expect it to do what you want.

I would recommend a subquery:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT task_id, task_time, create_time,
              (@rn := (CASE WHEN @p = concat_ws(':', task_id, task_time) THEN 1
                            WHEN @p := concat_ws(':', task_id, task_time) THEN @rn + 1
                            ELSE @rn + 1
                       END)
              ) AS rank,
       FROM instances CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT @rn := 0, @p := '') params
       WHERE task_id in (1209, 1211)
       ORDER BY task_id, task_time DESC, create_time DESC;
      ) x
 WHERE rank = 1 ;
```

Notes:

- In the most recent versions of MySQL, you need an additional subquery.  `ORDER BY` does not work with variables without the subquery.
- MySQL does not guarantee the order of execution of expressions in a `SELECT`, so you should do all the assignments in one subquery.
- You can combine the expression that defines the groups into a single variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your sql works fine (although some small mistakes in it). Furthermore, I wonder know that why `having` doesn't work. Whether just as the comment said, it is because my setting for mysql doesn't implicitly group all the columns and becomes undefined behavior.